# React testing library test onBlur for Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, react-testing-library

I have a simple input field and a button. I need to cover it with tests. The problem is, I can't cover onBlur with the test because onBlur simply is never called in test. However, the onFocus is called.

Example:

So I change input field with fireEvent.change -> then I click Continue and it should call the onBlur event, but if I run my test case then the console.log for onBlur is not called. I can do it with fireEvent.blur but that is not correct, because then I manually call it. But in real life on the onBlur, I have a function that changes something else for another element on the screen (not this file).

My react file

```html
<div>
   <input
   name="name"
   id="project"
   placeholder={"Name of your project"}
   onFocus={console.log("Focus called")}
   onBlur={console.log("Blur called")}
   />
   <button>Continue</button>
</div>
```

My test file :

```js
it('Should submit the answer', async () => {
        renderWithProviders(
            <ProjectNamePage />
        );

        expect(await screen.findByPlaceholderText('Name of your project')).toBeInTheDocument();

        fireEvent.change(screen.getByPlaceholderText('Name of your project'), { target: { value: 'First project' } });

        fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Continue'));

        // fireEvent.blur(screen.getByPlaceholderText('Name of your project')); 
        
        expect(mockedNavigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/smth', undefined);
    });
```

Why onBlur is not called and onFocus is? How could I call onBlur automatically not with fireEvent.blur?